# Appengine Go1.11 beta deployment failure

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am trying my hands on Go, and started with the go1.11 beta.
The first Hello world example worked fine and I was able to view it via the browser.

In my second attempt, I created multiple .go files (main.go, datastore.go).
I am able to run it locally and it works fine.

However when I attempt to deploy, I get the following error (deployment in first example worked just fine):

```
gcloud app deploy
...
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 67d67177-13cd-4e80-980a-ea36a0760678 status: FAILURE.
Build error details: go build: cannot use -o with multiple packages
```

On the server, the build logs show:

```
Step #1 - "builder": building app with command '[go build -o /tmp/staging735225713/usr/local/bin/start ./...]', env '[PATH=/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/builder/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin HOSTNAME=d0f271c7f5b8 HOME=/builder/home BUILDER_OUTPUT=/builder/outputs DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GOROOT=/usr/local/go/ GOPATH=/go GOPATH=/tmp/staging735225713/srv/gopath]': err=exit status 1, out=go build: cannot use -o with multiple packages
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/go111_app_builder:go111_20181212_RC00" failed: exit status 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Tried various things, including subfolder or a 'vendor' folder as suggested, but no avail.

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 79c39e82-3185-4ae1-a7ff-6afa1be448e7 status: FAILURE.
Build error details: srv/proto/myfile.pb.go:8:2: cannot find package "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOROOT)
    /tmp/staging770905501/srv/gopath/src/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: How are you running it locally? I mean what command and args are you using to run the local instance? And what are the `package` declarations in those multiple files? Are you using `package main` in both? Or something else?

Comment: yes, both files have 'package main'. I run it locally using 'go run main.go datastore.go'

Comment: and running 'go build' generates the binary as well

Comment: Have you got any other go files in the project's directory?

Comment: ah I forgot to mention that I also have a proto/myfile.pb.go file in that folder which is being referenced by main.go and works fine locally

Comment: What's the package declaration of that pb.go file?

Comment: package name is: com_plotter

Comment: What about your yaml file, how does that look?

Comment: Just to clarify, the problem stems from, I believe, the fact that appengine is attempting to build your app using `go build` with `-o` and with `./...`. If you read the section on `-o` [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) and if you know that `./...` will attempt to build subpackages as well you'll understand what the error `go build: cannot use -o with multiple packages` indicates...

Comment: ...  and that appengine probably shouldn't use `./...` in its build command. I haven't used appengine for ages now and I do not have it installed but if you can configure it so that it doesn't use `./...` you may be able to fix the problem.

Comment: thanks. yaml is plain boring: 'runtime: go111'

Comment: ... and if you're unable to configure appengine to not use `./...` you may be able to work around the issue by putting the com_plotter package into an adjacent directory as opposed to a subdirectory. Alternatively you should also be able to vendor the dependency, ie putting it under the `<my_project>/vendor` because I believe `go build` with `./...` skips over files that live under the vendor directory.